# Modal window with form does not close when submit in MVC5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, modal-dialog

There is a modal form within a main view which I call with the following button:

```
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#agregarProducto">Agregar Material </a>
```

[image: modal]

The code of my modal window within my main view is the following:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="agregarProducto">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">               
                <h5 class="modal-title">Agregar Material</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-info">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                    <strong>Tener en cuenta!</strong> <a> para agregar más de una unidad habilite</a><strong> agregar cantidad.</strong>
                </div>
                <form id="myForm">
                    <label>Agregar Cantidad</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="checkbox" id="idcheckcantidad" />
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cantidad" id="idcantidad" disabled="disabled" />
                    <br />
                    <label>Codigo Producto</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codigoproducto" id="idcodigoproducto" autofocus="true" />
                </form>
            </div>            
             <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" value="Agregar Material" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>                
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in the head structure of my html I have referenced the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-superhero.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and my javascript is the following:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

                var myformdata = $("#myForm").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Despachos/AgregarProducto",
                    data: myformdata,
                    success: function () {                     
                        $("#agregarProducto").hide();                       
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    </script>
```

and in my BundleConfig you have:

[image: Bundle]

This form calls a POST method on my controller ..

```
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AgregarProducto(int codigoproducto, int? cantidad)
        {  
           return View();
        }
```

The problem occurs when I click on the submit of the form, this modal window is not hiding even though when putting a break point in my post method it is executed

Why am I getting this behavior? Is it the first time I work with modal forms, any help for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.ajax` `HttpPost` request is expecting a response, but you are returning a View.

If you modify your $.ajax function to:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Despachos/AgregarProducto",
    data: myformdata,
    success: function () {
        $("#agregarProducto").hide();
    },
    error: function (xhr, text, error) {
        console.log(xhr.status + " => " + error);
    }
});
```

You should see the error in the console.

If you modify `AgregarProducto` to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AgregarProducto(int codigoproducto, int? cantidad)
{  
    var jsonResult = "Json Result";
    return Json(jsonResult);
}
```

Your modal should close (if you modify the success function as suggested in the comments).

If you do want to return a View, you need to find another way; for example, return the View as a string from the `HttpPost` Action as part of the `Json` response, or set `window.location.href = "Path/To/Controller/For/View";` in `$.ajax success`

Comment: Your answer to hidden the modal, but it leaves the screen blocked and dark !! what a headache !!, when debugging in my console the following error appears: "XML Parsing Error: no root element found .... Line Number 1, Column 1:" ... why am I still getting this inappropriate behavior? @RickL

Comment: I think that's a different problem - possibly due to malformed html (but it could be something else). Did you include $("#agregarProducto").modal('hide'); in the $.ajax success function to close the modal, because if you just use .hide() it may have thrown out the html (maybe)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Bootstrap, I think your syntax is off...should be like this:

```
$("#agregarProducto").modal('hide');
```

Comment: his answer did not help to solve the problem @BYates

Comment: Can you verify that the form is actually getting submitted successfully via AJAX?

Comment: if it is sent, the behavior is very strange ... in my web console I do not have any error either @BYates

Comment: @BYates has shown the correct syntax. $("#agregarProducto").hide(); is a standard jQuery way to hide an element, it isn't for hiding the bootstrap modal. Also make sure that you have shown the bootstrap modal using $("#agregarProducto").modal('show'). Lastly, have you verified that you are receiving a 200 code from your ajax call?

Comment: Make sure you use the F12 tools to see what status codes you are getting back from the server. You may not see any errors but there could still be some and they have been swallowed.